# Restrict ng-bootstrap modal from closing if clicked outside or ESC button

Tags: angular

I am using ng-bootstrap to open a modal for my angular2 project. The modal is getting dissolved if I click outside and also ESC button. I want to restrict these two behavior. Below is my code to open the modal

```
import { NgbModal, NgbModalOptions } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
.....
modalOption: NgbModalOptions = null;
constructor(
private modalService: NgbModal,
....
}
....
//the method I am using to open a modal
openAddModal() {
    this.modalOption.backdrop = 'static';
    this.modalOption.keyboard = false;
    const modalRef =  this.modalService.open(PremiumProtectionComponent,this.modalOption);
    .....
}
```

PremiumProtectionComponent is the ts file for the modal.

Below is the HTML where I have called the method

`<a (click)="openAddModal()">Click to open modal</a>`

Can anybody suggest me the correct way to achieve this behavior. Thanks in advance

Comment: `this.modalOption.backdrop = 'static'; this.modalOption.keyboard = false;` didn't work?

Comment: what if you try ith a fat arrow function? openAddModal = () =>{ ... }

Comment: @dfsq When I am trying to run the modal it is giving me error "Cannot set property 'backdrop' of null". I can understand I am missing something in the PremiumProtectionComponent but not sure what

Comment: the focus is moving outside of modal when the tab clicking---how to fix

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to set `backdrop` and `keyboard` properties on modalOptions *object*, not `null`:

```javascript
modalOption: NgbModalOptions = {}; // not null!

// ...

openAddModal() {
    this.modalOption.backdrop = 'static';
    this.modalOption.keyboard = false;
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(PremiumProtectionComponent,this.modalOption);
}
```

Comment: yes exactly. It was really my bad to set the options as null. Thanks a lot.

Comment: the focus is moving outside of modal when the tab clicking---how to fix

Answer (score 9):

You can add the ngModelOptions directly.

```
openAddModal() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(PremiumProtectionComponent,{
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });
}
```